# Div tag not reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am attempting to reload only a `div` tag on a page when there is new content in the database

in Ajax I test for new content:

```
function adshandler() {
var d = new Date();
var cache = d.getTime();
$.getJSON("check_time.php?cache=" + cache, function(update) {
    if (update.count === true) {
        //location.reload();
        $('#slideshow').reload();
    }
}); 
} 
setInterval(adshandler, 10000);
```

The `div` is on the same page as the ajax:

```
//Monday Afternoon
if ($dayofweek == "Monday" && $timeofday >= "12:00:00" && $timeofday <= "16:59:59"){
//Monday afternoon timeslot
echo "<div id='slideshow'>";
$stma= $conn->prepare("SELECT `Monday_Afternoon`
FROM `Client_Ads`");
$stma->execute();
while($resultst = $stma-> fetch()){
$mondayafternoonlist = $resultst["Monday_Afternoon"];
echo "<div class='slideshow'>";
echo "<img src='/$mondayafternoonlist'>";
echo "</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
}
```

There are more than one `div with a similar`id`and`class`, each one behind an`if`and`else if` statement, depending on the day of the week etc.

My `$('#slideshow').reload();` is not working?
I have also tried `$('#slideshow').load();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using `.load()` function in very few line. Following is a working example.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function changeDate() {
        $("#d2p").load(location.href + " #d2");
    }
</script>
<div id="d1p">
    <div id="d1">
        <?php echo date("H : i : s"); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the `DIV` which is going to refreshed on click of button partially on this page.

```
<div id="d2p">
    <div id="d2">
        <?php echo date("H : i : s"); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="changeDate();">Change Date</button>
```

Here is the demo [Load div without refreshing entire page](http://javascriptsolution.com/load-div-without-refreshing-entire-page/)

Comment: Thanks, but this wont work. The funtion needs to happen 1) based on time interval as in my AJAX.2) Happens when there is an update in the database.3) Happen without the push of a button. Your demo is to refresh an entire page, which can be done using `location.load;`, however the `$("#d2p").load(location.href + " #d2");` line helped me see the light. Thanks

Comment: Either set an ajax polling / push state monitoring to get changes in db or use node js socket.io

Answer (score 0):

```
function adshandler() {
var d = new Date();
var cache = d.getTime();
$.getJSON("check_time.php?cache=" + cache, function(update) {
if (update.count === true) {
    //location.reload();
   $("#slideshow").load(location.href + " #slideshow");
}
}); 
} 
setInterval(adshandler, 10000);
```